# Unity No Shading "Fullbright"

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, light, pixel-shading

Is there a way to fullbright your Level in Unity3D?

I just want to remove shading and lights in a surreal project to get a fullbright world where textures are always shown as they are intented to be, not with shadows from other objects, floors, walls and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide a custom shader for this purpose, such as the shader prepared here: http://blog.jappie.net/unity3d-fullbright-shader-with-transparency/.